# Prove that $f\left ( x \right )- x^{2021}$ always has at least one root $x_{0}\in\left ( 0, 1 \right )$

Tags: integration, functions, roots, boundary-value-problem, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Given positive continuous function $f\left ( x \right )$ on the interval $\left [ 0, 1 \right ]$ so that $\int_{0}^{1}f\left ( x \right ){\rm d}x< \frac{1}{2022}.$ Prove that $f\left ( x \right )- x^{2021}$ always has at least one root $x_{0}\in\left ( 0, 1 \right ).$

Suppose that there no exists $x_{0}\in \left ( 0, 1 \right )$ as the statement, let $g\left ( x \right )= f\left ( x \right )- x^{2021}.$ Because $f\left ( x \right )$ is a continuous function on $\left [ 0, 1 \right ]$ so $g\left ( x \right )$ too, then $g\left ( x \right )= kF\left ( x \right )$ with $F\left ( x \right )> 0, k= constant.$ On the other hand $g\left ( 0 \right )= f\left ( 0 \right )> 0\Rightarrow k> 0\Rightarrow g\left ( x \right )> 0,$

let $G\left ( x \right )= \int_{0}^{1}g\left ( x \right ){\rm d}x.$ We obtain ${G}'\left ( x \right )> 0,$ it reminds me the following inequality with strictly decreasing $f\left ( x \right )$ for all $x\in \left [ 0, 1 \right ]$ by Cauchy-Schwarz $\int\limits_{0}^{1}f\left ( x \right ){\rm d}x+ (\int\limits_{0}^{1}xf\left ( x \right ))^{2}> -1.$ How should I try next ? I need to the help, thank you.

Comment: you should write $f-x^{222}$ instead of $f=x^{..}$.

Comment: @dawNo problem.

Comment: And you should write $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$.

Comment: @ChrystomathOk.

Comment: Consider me skeptical, $2021$ makes me think that it might be from a math contest. If yes, and if its from a current contest, this has to be deleted.

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: @leoli1 thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0)>0$ is crucial for this. (Otherwise $\epsilon x^{2021}$ would be a counter-example for small enough $\epsilon$).

If $f(x) -x^{2021}$ is never zero then it is always positive or always  negative (by IVP). If it is always negative we get a  contradiction by letting $x \to 0$. If it is always positive we get a contradiction to $\int_0^{1} f(x) dx <\frac 1 {2022}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\int_0^1 g(x)dx=\int_0^1 f(x)-x^{2021}dx<0$ there has to be some $x_1\in (0,1)$ with $g(x_1)<0$. Since $g(0)>0$ by the intermediate value theorem there has to be a $x_0\in (0,1)$ with $g(x_0)=0$.